# apache/htaccess url rewriting help 

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Okay what i want to do is ...

```
http://domain.com/hdu79ejo
```

above should be redirected to

```
http://domain.com/client/?share=hdu79ejo
```

where `hdu79ejo` can be any value.

But ...

```
http://domain.com/client
```

and

```
http://domain.com
```

should not be redirected at all.

Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(client)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/?share=$1 [L]
```

it works fine except `http://domain.com` also getting redirected to `http://domain.com/client/?share=` .

Thanks for help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add another `RewriteCond`.  Something like this should work (untested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/?share=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your rewrite cond to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^client|^$)
```

Comment: ah when i changed it shows 404 on http://domain.com/5iWxD0GZVVk so it means it is not redirecting it .